# My Custom AccessDeniedHandler cannot called

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my `Spring Boot` app, I have implemented a custom `AccessDeniedHandler`, but it is never called, and the custom `authenticationEntryPoint` is called instead of it.

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPointImpl unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    private YzlAccessDeniedHandler yzlAccessDeniedHandler;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/yzl/**").access("@yzlAccessImpl.hasPermit(request)")
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();
        httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .accessDeniedHandler(yzlAccessDeniedHandler);
    }
}
```

the custom AccessDeniedHandler

```
@Component
public class YzlAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler, Serializable {

   @Override
   public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                      HttpServletResponse response, 
                      AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
     response.setStatus(403);
     response.getWriter().write("Forbidden: access error" + accessDeniedException.getMessage());
   }
}
```

the custom AuthenticationEntryPointImpl

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEntryPointImpl implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpServletResponse response, 
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
        response.setStatus(401);
        response.getWriter().write("Forbidden: Authentication failed");
    }

}
```

I let the custom Method in the `accessImpl` return always `false`, and I expect the response is `"Forbidden: access error"` while it was `"Forbidden: Authentication failed"`.

```
@Component 
public class YzlAccessImpl implements YzlAccess {
     
    @Override     
    public boolean hasPermit(HttpServletRequest request) {         
       return false;     
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate limitation of the way `Spring Security` handles its own exceptions. You can read more about it at the bug report (which was rejected) at `Spring Security`:

- [AccessDeniedHandler and AuthenticationEntryPoint does not work Because of the global exception handler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6908#issuecomment-533269673)

The only thing to do in this case is to spot `Spring Security` related exceptions in your *ExceptionHandler* and *rethrow* them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5ruE.png)